# How to Deploy Rust Axum API using Dokku

Tags: amazon-web-services, rust, digital-ocean, dokku, rust-axum

I have tried to deploy an API written in Rust ( Axum Framework ) but I get the error below, how do I accomplish this, there is no official documentation on this.

```
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
-----> Cleaning up...
-----> Building api from herokuish
-----> Adding BUILD_ENV to build environment...
       BUILD_ENV added successfully
-----> Unable to select a buildpack
remote:  ! Failure during app build
remote:  ! Removing invalid image tag dokku/api:latest
remote:  ! App build failed
```

I tried adding a Dockerfile but I still get the same Error.

Comment: Maybe ther dockerfile is not with a uppercase D? https://dokku.com/docs/deployment/builders/dockerfiles/ - A `Dockerfile` must exist in the root of the app repository.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to deploy by updating the custom Dockerfile and Introduced Procfile with contents bellow:-
Also I noticed the app must run on port 5000 to be exposed, unless you change the configurations.

Dockerfile

```
    # Use the official Rust image as the base image
    FROM rust:bookworm as builder
    
    # Set the working directory inside the container
    WORKDIR /usr/src/app
    
    
    
    ENV SQLX_OFFLINE=true
    
    
    # Copy the Cargo.toml and Cargo.lock files to the working directory
    COPY Cargo.toml Cargo.lock ./
    
    
    # Build dependencies to cache them
    
    
    RUN mkdir src && \
        echo "fn main() {}" > src/main.rs && \
        cargo build --release && \
        rm -rf src
    
    # Copy the rest of your source code
    COPY . .
    
    
    # Build your Rust application
    RUN cargo build --release
    
    # Create a new lightweight image without the build dependencies
    FROM debian:bookworm-slim
    
    RUN apt-get update && apt install -y openssl
    
    # Set the working directory inside the container
    WORKDIR /usr/src/app
    
    # Copy the built binary from the builder stage
    COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/target/release/main ./
    COPY --from=builder /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
    
    # Expose any necessary ports
    EXPOSE 5000
    
    # Command to run your application
    CMD ["./main"]
```

Procfile

```
    web: ./main
```